# Actual Number of Rows in Execution Plan is different than actual rows returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, sql-execution-plan

I've studied few questions that were already asked about "Actual Number of Rows" but none matched my problem and so posting it.
Also, I studied https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2018/05/28/actual-number-of-rows-are-not-always-accurate/ on why Actual Rows differ but this blog spoke about NonClustered Column Store Indexes which isn't relevant to my table.

Using https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/, queried **Users** table with "Actual Execution Plan" included-

```
SELECT TOP 10 Location FROM Users WHERE Location = 'Hyderabad'
SELECT TOP 10 Location FROM Users WHERE Location LIKE 'Hyderabad'
```

The Results are attached.
[StackOver_Top10HydUsers_ActualExecPlanIssue.Jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9rAN.jpg)
Questions are (based on my understanding how WHERE operators work ) -

1. Both queries yielded same type of Exec Plan. But both showed different "Actual Number of Rows" in the plan. How & Why?
2. The "Actual Number of Rows" of both plans were wrong since both queries
   returned 10 records. So, is "Actual Number of Rows" a misnomer? I
   studied why Estimated Rows differs based on reasons of Statistics
   but "Actual Rows" also !?

-- In 'thoughts'...

UPDATE # 1:
Actually I was intending to understand how could ActualRows differ than what is returned even after PhysicalOp Clustered Id Scan happened which actually counted records that satisfied WHERE.

Comment: Download the database file, install sql server, restore the database, and run the query in SSMS on your local machine and see if the execution plan is the same.

Comment: I see actual rows 10 for both queries. See if you can repeat your observations and  upload those xml plans [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) so we can review the details. Screenshots don't show all plan details.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for reply! #1. I re-ran the queries that I stored @[link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1078966/top-10-hyderabad-users#executionPlan) . Still the "Clustered Index" node shows "Actual Rows" as 0 & 3 but not 10. Please tell if you ran the queries on StackExchange or another way? #2. Exec Plan @ [link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJVTmXVMS) #3. When XML plan is studied, under "RunTimeCountersPerThread" and for each "Thread" there's "ActualRows". Sum up of ActualRows yields 10 which Brent's Graphical plan is showing but not the StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your statistics (that determine what index is to be used and how many rows are likely to be read) is off. Please don't set up a job to rebuild all statistics every hour or every day (its very like unnecessary and can be expensive) but rebuild the statistics on this table by:

```
update statistics schemaname.tablename with fullscan;
```

Usually this will sync up the query plan with the actual plan. Rebuilding indexes on a table will update all the statistics but this may not be necessary.

To rebuild all the indexes on a given table you can issue:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON schemaname.tablename REBUILD;
```

The advantage of doing this is that all fragmentation will be resolved and up to date statistics will be available for this table. On a large table this could take a while.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I see are Statistics available on this column. Query @ [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1079478/tables-and-available-stats) and Stats are recent too.